# Saving lists with kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I wrote a kivy app, which is supposed to save a list of strings.
But when I try to append a new String to the list I get this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Here is the function, which is supposed to make and save the list:

```
def save(self, vinput):
    store = JsonStore('hello.json')
    self.ueberschrift = ([])
    if store.exists('tito'):
        self.ueberschrift = store.get('tito')
    self.ueberschrift.update(vinput)
    store.put('tito', list_of_cap=self.ueberschrift)
```

I left the rest of the app and the import commands out, because these parts are working fine.

Comment: What does tito and vinput look like?

Comment: Tito is the name of the json store and vinput is the string, which I put in the function, they ate both strings, and I got no assci error